# Kendo Grid & Angular: row filtering for boolean will not work when data is supported via k-data-source attribute

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I wanted to have a row filter with dropdown for boolean in Kendo UI Grid.

After some hours of search I found this helpful article 
[KendoUI Grid row filter with dropdown for boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482969/kendoui-grid-row-filter-with-dropdown-for-boolean) with a link to a pretty working example http://dojo.telerik.com/alepI

But it won't work in my angular environment. After spending some hours I found out that the way of binding the data to the kendo grid does the trick.

With angular and its asynchronously loading data I found it very useful to separate the grid-data from the grid-options. So I used normaly this way in the HTML template:

```
<kendo-grid 
    options="vm.gridOptions" 
    k-data-source="vm.gridData" 
    k-ng-delay="vm.gridOptions">
</kendo-grid>
```

and defining the data in the angularJs-file like:

```
angular.module('my').factory('myGridCtrl', myGridCtrl);
function myGridCtrl() {
    vm.gridData = [
        {id: 1, ProductName: 'foo', Discontinued: false}
        {id: 2, ProductName: 'bar', Discontinued: true}
        ....
    ];

    vm.gridOptions = {
         // defining the options like in the example (without the data)
    };
 }
```

But the row filter with dropdown for boolean won't work. The error message was ".toLowerCase is not a function". The answer to that question was, to define the data field to "Boolean". But like in the dojo-example I already have defined the data-field as "Boolean".

The way to get the filter work was to define the HTML-template like:

```
<kendo-grid 
    options="vm.gridOptions"  
    k-ng-delay="vm.gridOptions">
</kendo-grid>
```

And the angularJs like:

```
angular.module('my').factory('myGridCtrl', myGridCtrl);
function myGridCtrl() {
    var gridData = [
        {id: 1, ProductName: 'foo', Discontinued: false}
        {id: 2, ProductName: 'bar', Discontinued: true}
        ....
    ];

    vm.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            data: gridData
        }
        // defining all other options like in the example (without the data)
    };
 }
```

So my question is: why is there a difference in binding the data to the kendo grid via html-attribute or js-object?

And which will be the best way binding the data to kendo grid using angular?

**THE SOLUTION**

When using angular with Kendo UI Grid, is it necessary to bind the data with the k-data-source attribute. And the data array has to be an DataSource object. Otherwise the grid is not updated when the data changes (very important when using angular). More to read http://www.telerik.com/blogs/a-few-angular-kendo-ui-best-practices

With this in mind I have to give the field-type definition another try. I defined all fields in the 'dataSource/model/fields'-Part of the options and now it works. Can't tell why it is working now.

Comment: where did you define the variable as boolean? because that indeed IS the solution, you just have to do it right ;)

Comment: Have you tried setting the column value types. Like here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

Comment: I have tried it in the 'column'-part also as in the 'dataSource/schema/model/fields'-part as described in the dojo-example.

Comment: Both variants work in the dojo-example and won't in my environment.